# PHP MySQL Syntax Error 'You have an error in your SQL syntax'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I cannot figure out the issue with my code here. I am trying to take info from the table, then subtract 1 second from Current_Time which looks like '2:00'. The problem is, I get:

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Current_Time) VALUES('22')' at line 1"

I don't even understand where it gets 22 from.

Thanks, I really appreciate it.

```
<?php

$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'aleckaza_admin', 'pswd');
if (!$connection) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

if (isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['time'])) {
    mysql_select_db("aleckaza_pennyauction", $connection);
    $query = "SELECT Current_Time FROM Live_Auctions WHERE ID='1'";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        $newTime = $row['Current_Time'] - 1;
        $query = "INSERT INTO Live_Auctions(Current_Time) VALUES('".$newTime."')";
        $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
    }
}

if (isset($_GET['getTime'])) {
    mysql_select_db("aleckaza_pennyauction", $connection);
    $query = "SELECT `Current_Time` FROM Live_Auctions WHERE ID='".$_GET['getTime']."'";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}

function beginGetAllInfo() {
    GLOBAL $connection;
    mysql_select_db("aleckaza_pennyauction", $connection);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Live_Auctions";
    $results = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        if (!isset($_GET['getTime'])) {
        echo "
        <table width=200px height=360px cellspacing=0 cellpadding=1 style='border-color: #000; border-style: solid; border-width: 1px;'>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2 style='font-size: 14px; color: #2700EB; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;'><center><strong>".$row['Product_Name']."</font></strong></center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan=2><center><img width=70% src='".$row['Image_URL']."'></center></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td id='txtHint' colspan=2 bgcolor=#000 height=90px><center><font color=#fff size=5px>$".$row['Current_Price']."</font><br /><font color=#fff size=3px>Timer set @ ".$row['Current_Timer']."sec</font><br /><font color=#fff size=5px>".$row['Current_Time']."</font><br /></center></td>
            </tr>
        </table>";
        } else {

        }
    }
}

?>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Auction</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
function getTime()
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","auction.php?getTime=1",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}

while (1) {
    getTime();
}
</script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php beginGetAllInfo(); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$newTime = $row['Current_Time'] - 1;` is returning 22 instead of time

Answer (score 1):

Current_Time is a keyword in MySQL, try putting ` around it (that's not a single quote btw, it's a backtick [thx maiorano84] - above the TAB key)

```
$query = "SELECT `Current_Time` FROM Live_Auctions WHERE ID='1'";
```

and

```
$query = "INSERT INTO Live_Auctions(`Current_Time`) VALUES('".$newTime."')";
```

EDIT:

I would change your SELECT statement to:

```
$query = "SELECT DATE_ADD(`Current_Time`, INTERVAL '-1' MINUTE) FROM Live_Auctions WHERE ID='1'";
```

Comment: "Backticks" is the term you're looking for.

Comment: Did you put it in your insert and select statements?  It looks like you're using CURRENT_TIME twice.

Comment: Yah I did, but it doesn't do anything different.

Comment: What is the datatype for Current_Time in the database?  You're passing in 22.  Is that a valid value for that field?  It's blowing up on the INSERT, but syntactically it looks ok to me...

Comment: Maybe `$newTime .":00"` and that way it will be "22:00"?

Comment: In the table, Current_Time is set to 2:00. I just want it to subtract 1 to make it 1:59 and keep going.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17532/discussion-between-alec-and-adam-plocher)

Comment: See my updated answer.  I would use MySQL to do that if you can.  Otherwise you need to parse the date in PHP and subtract the time properly.  Doing a simple -1 won't work.

Comment: Does the query you just added go in the first query or in the while?

Comment: Replace your first SELECT query with that and change `$newTime = $row['Current_Time'] - 1;` to `$newTime = $row['Current_Time'];`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE ID='1'' at line 1

Comment: I posted all the code in my file if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Current_Time is a reserve function in sql

//change this line from this :
$query = "INSERT INTO Live_Auctions(Current_Time) VALUES('".$newTime."')";

//to this :
//surround the Current_Time with backtick (not single quote)
$query = "INSERT INTO Live_Auctions(`Current_Time`) VALUES('".$newTime."')";
```

Comment: No, it just gave me a bolded PHP error.